# Selectively storing command history to a separate file

Tags: fish

I would like to modify the history mechanism in fish shell so that all commands starting with 'apt' should (also) be stored in a separate file.

Is there a way of doing it without recompiling fish? It would be nicer if I could turn this feature on/off.

Thanks!

Comment: Would just an occasional `history | egrep '^apt' > ~/apt_history.txt` be sufficient?

Comment: Yes and no.  I do that now.  But this would be more convenient - or so I think not having tried the proposed way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely want to do instead is to look in /var/log/apt/, where apt stores its logs. Those are much more authoratitive than anything you can hack together in a shell, because apt actually writes them.

---

Now, if you must do it in fish, you can hook into fish's events, like the `fish_preexec` event that is run before a command is executed:

```
function saveapt --on-event fish_preexec
    # The event hands the commandline over as the first argument
    # This really just checks if the commandline starts with 'apt',
    # so it won't e.g. detect `command apt` or calling it via functions
    # or scripts.
    if string match -r '^apt' -- $argv
        echo (date) $argv >> ~/apt_history.txt
    end
end
```

save in an eagerly sourced file like config.fish or conf.d/*.fish

Comment: To switch between disabling and re-enabling it, I will have to move that file in and out of the conf.d/ directory, I take it. (Which may not be that bad, now that I think about it!)

Comment: Yes, or you could check a flag variable or similar.

Comment: Or, as a reminder to me and for others who may visit this page, I should do: "functions -e saveapt".  This will erase from memory the function; but leave the file intact. Which means, if you open another terminal, it is available, of course. So once I am done saving the apt commands, I am moving the file out of conf.d/... directory AND doing a "erase" in the current shell.